# Another MVC routing problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

One day I'll understand routing but this is what I have:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");



            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{LicenceCode}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", LicenceCode = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

If I go to http://localhost all is ok

If I go to http://localhost/Home/Index/1234 all is ok

if I go to http://localhost/1234 it 404's

I tried Phil Haack's route debugger but because it throws a 404 the route debugger doesnt work.

What do I have to do In RegisterRoutes for http://localhost/1234 to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "LicenceCode",
    "{LicenceCode}"
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", LicenceCode = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Then `/1234` will route to the `Index` action of `Home` controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string licenceCode)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is this in addition to my current routes?  I have other controllers so I need the ability to go to http://localhost/basket for example

Comment: @Jon, you can't. How do you expect the routing engine to disambiguate between `/foo` and `/basket` where in the first case `foo` represents a license code and in the second a controller? That simply doesn't make sense. What you could do is to specify a regex route constraint a 4th argument to the `MapRoute` if for example your licence numbers followed some pattern. This way you could have the Licence route before the default route and the licence route will match if the constraint is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use following root instead of yours:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{LicenceCode}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", LicenceCode = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: How does it work when I got to other controllers though eg/http://localhost/basket

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Visual Studio in front of me, but I think it would be

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default2",
    "{LicenceCode}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", LicenceCode = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

You'll definitely want to put this last in your route registrations as this would hijack quite a few paths, I would imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a default route as mentioned above
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{LicenceCode}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", LicenceCode = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

but then DO NOT ADD 1,000 lines of routes in the global.asax I have seen this done on a few MVC 1 sites and it is really awful to maintain.

For other routes, handle them through Views and controllers.  Example:

1. In a Controller: in a ActionResults method, you can do
   return RedirectToAction("ClientEnrollment", "Cis");
2. In a view :  Having a link 
   @Html.ActionLink("Select", "ClientDetails", "Cis", new { id = item.ClientId }, null) |