# Is it possible to have multiple MVC routes point to the same controller/view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

(disclaimer: new to MVC)

I am trying to setup a website product listing with categories that lets the user request pages both by productfolder/productname and by productfolder/category/productname. Is that possible?

The closest I have gotten far was adding the following to the RouteConfig.cs RegisterRoutes method, and placed the ProductNameOne.cshtml in the Views\Products solution folder.  This results in being able to see the '.../Products/Index' and '.../Products/ProductNameOne' pages but '.../Products/CategoryOne/ProductNameOne' returns 404

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(name: "Products", url: "Products/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = 
            UrlParameter.Optional });


routes.MapRoute(name: "CategoryOneProducts", url: "Products/CategoryOne/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "ProductNameOne", id = 
            UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: You need to order your routes by *most specific route first.*

Comment: Robert's comment is the answer.  Swap Products route with CategoryOneProducts

Comment: now I am not so sure about this being possible, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6226639/832705 question answer points out that you can't expect the MVC processing to differentiate between a controller and an action

Comment: Should have worked...

Comment: @stackuser83 - comment to that post is about "/foo" "/bar" can't be distinguished without additional constraints (i.e. if you just have 2 routes `"{foo}"` and `"{bar}"`).

Answer (score 3):

You need to order your routes by *most specific route first.*

I'm guessing that your 404 URL is matching the first route, and then blowing up because `CategoryOne` does not exist as an ID.

Reorder your routes so that the `CategoryOne` route is tried first:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "CategoryOneProducts", url: "Products/CategoryOne/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "ProductNameOne", id = 
        UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(name: "Products", url: "Products/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = 
        UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: putting the url:"Products/CategoryOne/{action}/{id} route before the url:"Products/{action}/{id}" route seems to result in the automatic replacement of <a> tag hrefs of "Product/" being replaced by "Product/CategoryOne" is there some way to avoid that?

Comment: @stackuser83 - you can specify route name to most helpers... But you really should stop and think about mappings from url data to action and from route data to route you want to create. You may find out that some other Url structure (or route structure) is less confusing.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that is helpful about the helpers, I didn't think to have Razor generate the link URLs, they were static text and still replaced or prefixed by the route.  I was trying to make things simpler for website users and did end up in complicated route expressionland